# frame size and coordinates off (objective-c, ipad)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, frame

Supposedly this is a 10 by 10 square 100 pixels on the x axis from the origin and 100 pixels on the y axis from the origin (origin being the top left corner)
However it quite clearly wrong.
[image]

Writing the views frame to NSLog after setting it gives out the same values I put in.

Code:

```
ISScrollDock *bottomSV = [[ISScrollDock alloc] init];
[bottomSV.view setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 10, 10)];
[bottomSV.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self.view addSubview:bottomSV.view];
```

Here is an Xcode project to show my problem: http://www.qfpost.com/download.do?get=92f03538907e72665ea794d98ff8392b

Comment: Show the code for how you create/draw it please :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add

```
test.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
```

because your view currently has `autoresizingMask` on.

Comment: I fee kind of stupid now, thats what I get for trying to program for 15 hours

Comment: however I have another view that works like it should without setting autoresizemask.

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding this scroll view to another view or scroll view which has been scrolled up?  Check the frame location of the superview.

Comment: its not actually a scroll view yet, and there are no other scroll views.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck "Autoresize Subviews" in your xib file.

Now, where's my cake? :P